# Advanced Service Classroom is not working from yesterday

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

I have been working on a project the last few days that access advanced services, specifically Classroom. The project has the advanced services enabled -classroom- and also in the "Google Developer Console" is activated the API.

Suddenly it has stopped working and displays the following error:

```
  **ReferenceError: "Classroom" is not defined**
```

This is a sample script that reproduces the issue ( the Classroom example from GAS )

```
function listCourses() {
  var optionalArgs = {
    pageSize: 10
  };
  var response = Classroom.Courses.list(optionalArgs);
  var courses = response.courses;
  if (courses && courses.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
      var course = courses[i];
      Logger.log('%s (%s)', course.name, course.id);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No courses found.');
  }
}
```

( 21017-2-16) I think it's already fixed

Comment: I am getting the same issue since this morning.  I also tried some apps that sync with classroom and they are not working as well.  I can't seem to find anything online as to why this is happening.

Comment: File a report on this [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Defect%20report).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is issue that should be reported by using the [Classroom section on the Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/566255).